# I want to transfer a number from one file in Python to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can I, for example, copy this number from one file to another?

```
inp = int(input("Enter your number:"))
```

I want to copy the inp to another file and I want to use the number in the other file ,like this

another file:

```
print("", inp)
```

Can I do this and thank you.

Comment: you can `import` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it in a function, then import that function in the other file.

input.py

```
def input_number():
     inp = int(input("Enter your number"))
     return inp
```

Other file:

```
from input import input_number

inp = input_number()
print("", inp)
```

Comment: no need to make a function tho

Comment: Better practice imo. Reduces the amount of variables in the global name space :)

Comment: that's good, yeah, in this case tho, the amount of variables in the global name space doesn't change whether you use a function or not, but yeah, sure

Answer (score 1):

file1:

```
input_num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

file2:

```
from file1 import input_num
num = input_num
```

Comment: also make sure the variables have different names

Comment: you can edit your post, also why?

Comment: python might get confused

Comment: Python can't get confused, also add info to the answer, not in the comments

Comment: also you could get confused